# Referencing parent schema in sub-schema for JSON schema validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm working on a JSON schema and I'm not sure if I've designed this correctly and will appreciate any suggestions.

So I have a parent object called "Task.json" that references an inner object called "Data.json". Now I need a way to be able to validate the schema such that the required properties of "Data.json" vary depending on a property from "Task.json". For example, if Task.json contains "action = create" then we want the properties in data.json to be "a","b" or "c" while "action = update" should be "a", "d", "e". I'm not sure how I can reference the parent object (action) in data.json to be able to specify the valid properties depending on the "action" parameter.

Example:

> Task.json

```
{
   "oneOf":[
      {
         "action":"create",
         "data":"data.json"
      },
      {
         "action":"update",
         "data":"data.json"
      }
   ]
}
```

> Data.json

```
      {
   "properties":{
      "a":{

      },
      "b":{

      },
      "d":{

      },
      "e":{

      }
   },
   "oneOf":[
      {
         "#/action":{
            "enum":[
               "create"
            ]
         },
         "required":[
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
         ]
      },
      {
         "#/action":{
            "enum":[
               "update"
            ]
         },
         "required":[
            "a",
            "d",
            "e"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You reference sub-schemas with the `$ref` keyword. Your case is a little complicated to express, but it is definitely doable. Depending on the details of your use case, there are ways this can be simplified. I'm showing the most flexible design here.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "action": { "enum": ["create", "update", "delete"] },
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": {},
        "b": {},
        "d": {},
        "e": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/action-create-implies-abc" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/action-update-implies-ade" }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "action-create-implies-abc": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/action-create" } },
        {
          "properties": {
            "data": { "required": ["a", "b", "c"] }
          },
          "required": ["data"]
        }
      ]
    },
    "action-update-implies-ade": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/action-update" } },
        {
          "properties": {
            "data": { "required": ["a", "d", "e"] }
          },
          "required": ["data"]
        }
      ]
    },
    "action-create": {
      "properties": {
        "action": { "enum": ["create"] }
      },
      "required": ["action"]
    },
    "action-update": {
      "properties": {
        "action": { "enum": ["update"] }
      },
      "required": ["action"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I tried validating the above schema and it seems to ignore the "required" inside "properties" of "definitions". Just for testing purposes, I updated "required" to "enum" and then it seems to validate inside "properties" of anyOf. Seems like "required" does not work inside definitions/properties.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  But, this sound like it might be a separate question? The best way for me help might to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jason! Your example is great and makes me re-think the original design.

So I just got another layer added to it where in there is a "MetaData.json" inside Data.json and "create" requires "Data.json" and "a", "b" and "c" in "Metadata.json" while Update only requires "Metadata.json" with "a", "d" and "e" as required. In this case, is there a way to indicate inside of the definitions/properties that data.metadata's required properties are "a", "b' and "c"? This design follows the use-case that "update" operation might only require "metadata.json" to be passed.

Example:

> Data.json

```
    {
   "properties":{
      "x":{

      },
      "y":{

      },
      "z":{

      },
"metadata": {
      $ref: "metadata.json"
}
   }
```

> Metadata.json

```
{
   "properties":{
      "a":{

      },
      "b":{

      },
      "d":{

      },
      "e":{

      }
}
```